# Automatic file transfer over http or ftp in php or js?

Tags: file, http, networking, ftp, transfer

I'm looking for a solution to transfer files from one computer to another without any human interaction. I have a build server that needs to get the nightly build to another testing computer that evaluates the software and saves the results in a text file. When that is done, I need to get the text file back to the build server for the emailing and posting of the results. I've looked around a bit and found that it's not really possible to do this with forms for security reasons but this really isn't my area of expertise. I can't use a network share location because the network drives are not always in sync.

Some other ideas I had were running a ftp upload with the command line, having some kind of listen socket for both machines, and putting the file in a "to download" folder visible on a web server and notifying the other machine of what the filename is.

Are any of these better than the others or even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Using FTP & PHP for your condition is very possible. Back then I created a page that has to scan through a network and download some images using FTP (I used VSFTPD) regularly.
So perhaps all you need to do is setup your FTP server, then create the php script to download your file, and run the script regularly using cron job at when your file is created + 5 or 10 minutes.